# React Js can't Run using npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to run my project, but  npm start error -_-

````
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! breednder-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the breednder-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aziz/.npm/_logs/2020-02-15T09_11_32_000Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Can you show show the error log file ``/home/aziz/.npm/_logs/2020-02-15T09_11_32_000Z-debug.log``

Comment: https://github.com/kuibeatboxer98/belajar/blob/master/log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Did you try recovering your dependencies?**
run `npm install`

and make sure from Node and npm version at least 
npm more than 6 and node more than 10

```
npm -v 
node -v
```

and finally, try to delete the node_modules and package-lock 
and do `npm i` again

Comment: use "sudo npm start " to run the project , the problem on my linux is a permission

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before so I will share what my issue was:

in package.json just verify the integrity of you start command.  Also try `npm run start` (add run to it)

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project lacks the necessary dependency to back the "start": "react-scripts start" clause under your package.json. To fix this error, just delete your node_modules folder and run npm install again.